# Is it possible to use iota.rs libraries for both Shimmer and IOTA Chrysalis in the same Python app? and in a Docker container?

Tags: python, chrysalis, shimmer, iota.rs

For my application there is the requirement to run iota.rs for Shimmer and IOTA Chrysalis.

How is that possible?

Bonus question: how can I do that in a docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is only possible by building iota.rs from source.

In `bindings/python/native/Cargo.toml` change both names:

```
[package]
- name = "iota-client-python"
+ name = "iota-client-production"
  version = "0.2.0-alpha.3"
  authors = ["IOTA Stiftung"]
  edition = "2021"
  description = "Python bindings for the IOTA client library"
  documentation = "https://wiki.iota.org/iota.rs/welcome"
  homepage = "https://www.iota.org/"
  repository = "https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs"
  license = "Apache-2.0"
  keywords = ["iota", "tangle", "client", "python"]
  categories = ["cryptography::cryptocurrencies"]

[lib]
- name = "iota_client"
+ name = "iota_client_production"
  crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

In `bindings/python/native/setup.py`:

```
setup(
-   name="iota_client",
+   name="iota_client_production"
    version="0.1.0",
    classifiers=[
        "License :: SPDX-License-Identifier ::  Apache-2.0",
        "Development Status :: 0.1.0 - Alpha",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Programming Language :: Rust",
        "Operating System :: POSIX",
        "Operating System :: MacOS :: MacOS X",
    ],
    packages=["iota_client"],
    rust_extensions=[
        RustExtension(
            "iota_client.iota_client",
            rustc_flags=get_py_version_cfgs(),
            debug=False,
        ),
    ],
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

And in `bindings/python/native/src/lib.rs`:

```
/// A Python module implemented in Rust.
#[pymodule]
- fn iota_client(_py: Python<'_>, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
+ fn iota_client_production(_py: Python<'_>, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
      m.add_class::<Client>()?;
      Ok(())
  }
```

Install and run maturin:

```
pip3 install maturin
maturin develop
maturin build --manylinux off
```

The wheel file is now created in `bindings/python/native/target/wheels`. You can install it with:

`pip3 install [THE_BUILT_WHEEL_FILE]`

Once it has been properly installed you can double check it using pip:

`pip list`

You should see the similar output:

```
Package                    Version
-------------------------- -------
iota-client-production           0.2.0a3
```

From here it is necessary import the Chrysalis library using `iota_client_production`

```
import iota_client_production # for IOTA Chrysalis
from iota_client import IotaClient as ShimmerClient # Imported as ShimmerClient to prevent confusion
```

Reference: The Shimmer wiki shows [here](https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/iota.rs/how_tos/use-python-with-iota/) how to do that.

Bonus answer: Here the dockerfile with the information to build a container with both versions of iota.rs for Python.

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-bullseye

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app/

EXPOSE 8000

COPY requirements.txt /app

# Install required system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    libudev-dev \
    git \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    libdbus-1-dev \
    libusb-dev \
    libhidapi-dev \
    libhidapi-hidraw0 \
    libclang-dev \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Upgrade PIP
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Install Rust to compile libs
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y && \
    . $HOME/.cargo/env && \
    git clone -b develop https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs && \
    cd iota.rs/client/bindings/python && \
    pip install -r requirements-dev.txt && \
    pip install . && \
    cd /app/iota.rs && \
    git stash && \
    git checkout production && \
    cd bindings/python/native && \
    sed -i 's/name="iota_client",/name="iota_client_production",/g' setup.py && \
    sed -i 's/name = "iota-client-python"/name = "iota-client-production"/g' Cargo.toml && \
    sed -i 's/keywords = ["iota", "tangle", "client", "python"]/keywords = ["iota", "tangle", "client", "python","chrysalis"]/g' Cargo.toml && \
    sed -i 's/name = "iota_client"/name = "iota_client_production"/g' Cargo.toml && \
    cd src && \
    sed -i 's/fn iota_client/fn iota_client_production/g' lib.rs && \
    cd .. && \
    pip install maturin && \
    maturin build --manylinux off && \
    cd /app/iota.rs/bindings/python/native/target/wheels/ && \
    pip install iota_client_production-0.2.0a3-cp36-abi3-linux_x86_64.whl && \
    cd /app && \
    rm -rf iota.rs

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

COPY . /app

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/app/commands.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/commands.sh"]
```